# Oracle Forms Update Table using Multi-record

Tags: oracle, for-loop, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-cursor

I have a multi row block that looks like this in oracle forms:

[image]

My query:

```
Select * from table1;
```

Looks like this:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    3|
|    3|
|    7|
|    1|
+-----+
```

The column **value** is a column in a table to be updated into column **new**:

[image]

So that when I requery, the values on my table should be like this:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    4|
|    6|
|   14|
|    2|
+-----+
```

I tried on post form commit:

```
for i in 1 .. :rec_count
loop
    update table1
    set value = :new
    where value = :value;
end loop;
```

but this only updates the last record that i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be proper to use a *while loop* with *first_record* and *next_record* Built-ins from a button by *WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED* smart trigger with the following code :

```
declare
   v_blk varchar2(25) := 'block1';
begin   
   go_block(v_blk);
   first_record;
 while ( :value is not null ) 
 loop
  :value := :value + nvl(:added_value,0);
   next_record;
 end loop;

   commit_form;    

   go_block(v_blk);
   execute_query;
end;
```